# OpenLayers: Registering function to marker event does not work

Tags: dictionary, openlayers, marker

I have a map in OpenLayers with a simple layer and a marker layer. 
The markers in the marker layer are generated from `data.rows`. For every marker, I want to register a function to the "mousedown" (or "click") event, but that does not seem to work. The markers got added to the map, but upon clicking, the function registered to the event is not entered.

```
// Marker-Layer
    var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("SABA")

    // Icon
    var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21, 25);
    var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w / 2), -size.h);
    var iconPath = document.location.protocol + '//' + document.location.hostname + '/saba/modulesinst/sa/icons/pin.png';
    var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon(iconPath, size, offset);

    // Rows durchgehen
    Array.each(data.rows, function(item, index) {
        if (item.x != null && item.y != null) {
            var newmarker = new OpenLayers.Marker(new OpenLayers.LonLat(item.x, item.y), icon.clone())

            newmarker.events.register('mousedown', newmarker, function(evt) {
                alert(item.name);
                OpenLayers.Event.stop(evt);
            });
            markers.addMarker(newmarker);
        }
    });
    this.listMap.addLayer(markers);
```

Answer (score 5):

The Openlayers Documentation states that you should use a vector layer for this purpose instead of a marker layer: "Markers are the ‘older’ way to interact with geographic data in the browser. Most new code should, where possible, use vector layers in place of marker layers".

When you use a vector layer you can add markers like this:

```
var marker = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lon,lat), attributes);
vectorLayer.addFeatures(marker);
```

and you can use this code to initialize the vector layer:

```
function selected (evt) {
    alert(evt.feature.id + " selected on " + this.name);
}
var layer = new OpenLayes.Layer.Vector("VLayer");
layer.events.register("featureselected", layer, selected);
```

and finally this to add the select feature control to your map:

```
var control = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(layer);
map.addControl(control);
control.activate();
```

Refer to this [Openlayers Documentation](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/overlays.html)